# How do I build a web application using AWS IoT connecting to a factory floor?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-greengrass

I want to build a web application using aws Iot.
I build SCADA systems for different companies.

I have a modbus rtu master(raspi) connected to many slaves on a factory floor.
Modbus master is controlling a robotic arm and monitoring it's temperature, position, motor current and motor torque.
I have gone through many videos and websites to implement AWS IoT.

How do I make a user authentication based web application in which my clients can login to the web app and access their robot and control and monitor them.
I have connected my thing with AWS IoT over MQTT.
I have never built web apps.

Comment: Building websites is off topic for IoT Stack Exchange, if once you have a website the specifics of integrating it with AWS IoT may be on topic.

Comment: I think you should reword it to ask how to connect AWS with your web site.

Comment: Hi @user2326642, can you elaborate a bit what your current state of the solution is and what you're struggling to do? We're not a good SE site to give you generic information on building web apps. Currently this seems quite broad.

Comment: An IoT platform (any of them, AWS being the special case here) is supposed to make your (the developer) job easier to implement safe, robust apps. We have found all of them lacking. Some are better than others. Some allow rapid prototyping, others are unwieldy. We have our bias, and if interested and not married to AWS, google "samsung artik mimic mqtt" for an example close to what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I have created a similar application.  Your question covers a lot of ground.  You already have AWS and your "thing" working together.  The next job (might be) to decide what you want to expose via a web site.

There are many web frameworks available to you, I like python django.  I would create an interface between your AWS IoT flow to Django, probably through AWS lambda functions.  Alternatively, you might get some traction using AWS API gateway and lambda.

Good luck.  There is plenty of web development help on the main Stack Overflow site.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to send real time telemetry to your web application (say a dashboard) then look for a web socket implementation in the framework you choose for. for e.g if you plan to make the app in .net they have the signalr library for web socket support. Rest of the web development would be more or less in line with any other database driven web application.

The typical flow would be like this,

device -> aws iot rest api -> dashboard/Database

1) The device send data to your aws iot platform over a rest api.

2) Then the data should be sent to your dashboard using web sockets and should be stored in a db if you wish.

Also there are a lot of other points to be considered like should you use a message queue like rabbitmq or an in-memory data store like redis etc based on the scale of your app.

Again if you want to control your equipment in real time then using http may not be an option as messages cannot be sent from an http server to a client, instead consider amqp/mqtt.

Feel free to ask if you need more clarification as the topic is very broad.